# Creating New Forms in Laravel 5 and Submitting Them

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I wish to clarify the steps to get a new form properly submitted to my database using Laravel 5.2 and Bootstrap 3.

I have the login/register pages set up properly using Laravel's defaults, and they work fine. I now want to create a user profile page accessible to authenticated users. I am using one row in the database for all of their user info. Some fields were filled in during registration, and now I want them to have access to additional fields (while restricting access to certain registration fields like user name).

In the example code below, there are fields to upload a personal photo, enter a first name, and enter a last name. (None of these were done during registration.)

What I have already done (all code is below):

1. Create the view profile.blade.php
2. Create a controller profileController.php
3. Update routes.php in the controller directory.

A note:

1. When I try to submit the form as it appears below, I get, Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::update() must be of the type array, none given.

What are the next steps required to get this page working properly?

profile.blade.php:

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="container" style="padding-top: 30px;">
  <h1 class="page-header">User Profile</h1>
  <div class="row">

    <!-- left column -->
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="text-center">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-5x"></i>
        <h6>Please upload a photo...</h6>
        <input type="file" class="text-center center-block well well-sm">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- edit form column -->
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 personal-info">
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/profile') }}">

      {!! csrf_field() !!}
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">First name:</label>
          <div class="col-lg-8">
            <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo Auth::user()->firstname; ?>" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First..." type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Last name:</label>
          <div class="col-lg-8">
            <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo Auth::user()->lastname; ?>" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last..." type="text">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
              <i class="fa fa-btn fa-user"></i>Submit
            </button>
            <span></span>
            <input class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel" type="reset">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

profileController.php:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('profile');
    }
    protected function update(array $data)
    {
        return User::update([
            'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

And I added the following in the routes middleware:

```html
Route::get('/profile', 'ProfileController@index');

Route::post('/profile', 'ProfileController@update');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a protocol mismatch, since you're POSTing your form. You need to change your route to

```
route::post('/profile', 'ProfileController@index');
```

Using a validator is a great idea, since it will make sure that your input is exactly what you need it to be, and all required fields are filled out.

Your update function should look something like this:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $first_name = $request->input('firstname');
    $last_name = $request->input('lastname');
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $user = \App\User::find($id);
    $user->firstname = $first_name;
    $user->lastname = $last_name;
    $user->save();
    return view('profile');
    // Sanitize, validate, before you do ANYTHING with update
    // Instead of returning the update result, you can instead show another view or forward them to another page.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When I make that change, I get the same error message as before but now I get it when I try to access the profile page instead of when I click the submit button. Perhaps Laravel needs the get route for some other operation. I tried using the original get to access the page and then switching to post to submit the form, and that did not enter data into the fields in my DB. Is there some other intermediary step that I'm missing? For instance, I do not yet see how my form knows to access the correct table. Do I need to tell it which table to use somewhere?

Comment: If you want to use the same path, create two routes: a route for GET pointing to the loading function, then a POST route for processing the data.

Comment: Ok, I'm getting there. Could you look again at the code above? I made some changes but am still getting an error.

Comment: I'm going to update my answer with what you should have for your update function.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Where is the Input class located? (I get Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found.) Does it look like Laravel 5.2 might be moving away from using that class? The 5.2 documentation suggests something like public function update(Request $request) {$first_name = $request->input('firstname');} When I try that, I get an error saying that User::update can't be used statically.

Comment: It looks like Request is the way to go. Do you have a separate update function created in the User class? You may just need to instantiate the user ($user = User::find($id_of_the_user), then update the fields and save.

Comment: Yes, the latter suggestion works. Thanks. I hope you don't mind, but I edited your answer to reflect what we've discussed here. I do have one other question, if you have a moment. When I return the profile view, the old values show up in the form fields and do not reflect the database changes. I have to reload the page to get the new names to appear. Is there a way to make sure that database changes are reflected on the returned view by, say, automatically reloading the page or something?

Comment: It may not be refreshing the user. Instead of returning the view, redirect them back to the profile page. `return redirect()->to(/profile');`